# Where is the DNS Cache located? (Server 2003)

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, cache

I currently setup my network to do all DNS through our 2003 Server, and now that there is a Cache, I'd like to pull some reports on it.  I am a .NET developer and my idea is to parse a file and dump it into SQL Server.

The problem is that I don't know where Server stores the Cache. Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is all in memory.

I know you can use the [dnscmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778513%28WS.10%29.aspx) to dump the cache with a command like this:

```
dnscmd serverip /zoneprint .
```

You can view the contents of the with the DNS MMC.  From the View menu make sure the 'Advanced' option is checked.  You can then click on a server and under that will be a folder named 'Cached Lookups'.

There will be a performance cost, but what you may actually want to do is enable the debug logging and then run reports against the log file, instead of trying to look at the at just the cache.

To configure debug logging open up the DNS manager, right click on the server.  There is a tab 'Debug Logging'.  Set the path for the log file and check the boxes to log what you want to see.

Comment: which debug logging are you referring to?  My ultimate goal is to see all HTTP requests going through my network.  I figure since my server serves the DNS that this would be the logical spot.  I'm open to alternitaves...

Comment: oh, and also, evidently I do not have dnscmd on my server.

Comment: I am pretty sure you get dnscmd as part of the resource kit (http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en)

Comment: If I wanted to build reports based on HTTP requests, I personally would setup a proxy like squid.  I would force my clients through it by setting it up transparently, or distributing proxy settings via GPO.  Then I would use one of the many reporting tools designed for that (sarg, calamaris, etc...)

Comment: Well I just took a quick look at Squid and it's far more work than I'm willing to put in.. but thanks.

Comment: Of course the time required is heavily dependent on your experience.  I could setup a squid box with the reporting for a small/mid-sized network in 3-6 hours.  Writing a program to parse an obscure log file or the output of dnscmd would take me a lot longer.  Plus logs from a proxy server will give you far more detail, and accurate data then what you get from just looking at a dns cache.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Unfortunately my Router does not log enough info (IE it does not log http requests at all), and my only real option here is to install another box to use as a gateway.  Not really my cup of tea here... so I think I'm prolly gonna just have to leave it for now.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to look at http requests only, you'll have to use some sort of proxy or other network tool.

You could configure a server to be the gateway router and use a tool like Wireshark to analyze the traffic.

Another option is to use a feature of some managed network switches called port mirroring. You can mirror the traffic of the port of your existing gateway router to the port of another machine and use Wireshark to capture the data.

Comment: I took a quick look at Wireshark, but mirroring the router seems complicated.

Comment: also, this is just a home network, so my router is consumer grade (Dlink DIR-825)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the cache exists only in memory since the records in the cache are transient and will expire based on the TTL of the records. Anyone know anything different?